# Trying to add $sendtoname to message

Tags: php, email, message

Right now I have this:

```
$sendtoname = "John";
$sendtoemail = "john@email.com";
```

And this:

```
$message = "Dear ".$sendtoname;
$message .= ",<br><br>A new volunteer has registered for your ".$_REQUEST['pickevent'];
```

So that I receive a message that says,

```
"Dear John,

A new volunteer has registered for your event..."
```

But "John" does not appear; it shows up blank. How do I correct this?

**EDIT :**

Ok, here is my full code:

```
<?php
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    function stripslashes_deep($value)
    {
        $value = is_array($value) ?
                    array_map('stripslashes_deep', $value) :
                    stripslashes($value);

        return $value;
    }

    $_POST = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_POST);
    $_GET = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_GET);
    $_COOKIE = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_COOKIE);
    $_REQUEST = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_REQUEST);
}
//send an email from the server TO YOUR EMAIL

$fromname = $_REQUEST['firstname'];
$fromemail = $_REQUEST['email'];
$subject = "NMVN EVENT REGISTRATION";

$message = "Dear ".$sendtoname;
$message .= ",<br><br>A new volunteer has registered for your ".$_REQUEST['pickevent'];
$message .= " event. Below is a copy of their registration: ".$_REQUEST['blank'];
$message .= " <br><br><br> <b>First Name:</b> ".$_REQUEST['firstname'];
$message .= " <br> <b>Last Name:</b> ".$_REQUEST['lastname'];
$message .= " <br> <b>Cell Phone:</b> ".$_REQUEST['cellphone'];
$message .= " <br> <b>Alternative Phone:</b> ".$_REQUEST['altphone'];

//This is the person who is going to receive the email
switch ($_REQUEST["pickevent"])
{
    case 'Heart Walk 4/20/13':
        $sendtoname = "Bob";
        $sendtoemail = "bob@email.com";
        break;
    case 'Bowling Fundraiser 5/4/13':
        $sendtoname = "John";
        $sendtoemail = "john@email.com";
        break;
}

//Email header stuff
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "From: $fromname <$fromemail>\r\n";
$headers .= "To: $sendtoname <$sendtoemail>\r\n";
$headers .= "Bcc: me@myemail.com" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $fromname <$fromemail>\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Priority: 3\r\n";
$headers .= "X-MSMail-Priority: Normal\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: Created by Mike Gandy";

//this next line creates and sends the email
mail($sendtoemail, $subject, $message, $headers);

?>
```

The form is responding correctly otherwise, whereas it is sent to the correct person and BCC'd to me. All the other messages work fine, too. The only thing that doesn't work is that the $sendtoname doesn't appear in the message. It appears in the header just fine though.

Comment: Sorry? Does John appear in the message or not?

Comment: No, John does not appear in the message when I receive the email.

Comment: Is `$sendtoname` visible where you create `$message`? Is `$message` or `$sendtoname` created in a function?

Comment: @MikeGandy - could you add some more code, please? There's nothing obviously wrong with what you've posted, so perhaps the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Just edited my post with all my code. Any suggestions? Thanks for your help, guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your switch to before `$message`, as you are trying to use `$sendtoname` before it is declared.

```
//This is the person who is going to receive the email
switch ($_REQUEST["pickevent"])
{
    case 'Heart Walk 4/20/13':
        $sendtoname = "Bob";
        $sendtoemail = "bob@email.com";
        break;
    case 'Bowling Fundraiser 5/4/13':
        $sendtoname = "John";
        $sendtoemail = "john@email.com";
        break;
}

$message = "Dear ".$sendtoname;
$message .= ",<br><br>A new volunteer has registered for your ".$_REQUEST['pickevent'];
$message .= " event. Below is a copy of their registration: ".$_REQUEST['blank'];
$message .= " <br><br><br> <b>First Name:</b> ".$_REQUEST['firstname'];
$message .= " <br> <b>Last Name:</b> ".$_REQUEST['lastname'];
$message .= " <br> <b>Cell Phone:</b> ".$_REQUEST['cellphone'];
$message .= " <br> <b>Alternative Phone:</b> ".$_REQUEST['altphone'];
```

Comment: That's because the person filling out the form is not receiving the message. It's for an event page, whereas the volunteer registers, and the results are sent to the organizer of the event and BCC'd to me.

Comment: see my edited answer. You are trying to use `$sendtoname` before it is declared.